# appium driver throws Exception when using regex?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am using appium to do some ui automation.I am having problems with regex;
**WebDriverException** throwed with the code,and the element totally exists:
`phonedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[matches(@text,'sometext\\d+')]"))`

Here are exception message:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to evaluate expression. See cause
```

Here are my capability info:

```
Capabilities {appActivity: com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI, appPackage: com.tencent.mm, deviceName: 127.0.0.1:62001, fastReset: false, fullReset: false, newCommandTimeout: 999999, noReset: true, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 5.1.1, resetKeyboard: true, udid: 127.0.0.1:62001}
```

Here are my pom:

```
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.3.0</version>

<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `matches()` is only available in XPath 2.0 and not 1.0 see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches

Selenium, but also Chrome and Firefox browser are using Xpath 1.0. 
You can try any Xpath 2.0 functions in the JS-console of the browser and it will show you an error. e.g.: `$x("lower-case('ABC')")`

2. to get the text use `.` or `text()` e.g `$x("//*[contains(text(),'bob')]")`

As a solution for your problem, you can get all elements containing your text `"//android.view.View[contans(text(),'sometext')]")` and then loop through them in JAVA to find the correct one